# How to test method call times in react connected componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, tdd, enzyme

I'm trying to test react-redux component using Jest and Enzyme.

I passed basic rendering tests
But Can't test a custom method call times in componentDidMount.

**MyButton.jsx**

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.handleDataLoad = this.handleDataLoad.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleDataLoad();
  }
  handleDataLoad() {
    console.log('handleDataLoad call');
  }
  render() {
    {/* ... */}
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => (/* ... */);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyButton);
```

**MyButton.spec.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import MyButton from './MyButton';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('MyButton', () => {
  const initialState = {};
  const props = {
    /* ...required props... */
  };
  const store = mockStore(initialState);
  const component = shallow(<MyButton store={store} {...props} />);
  const didMount = jest.spyOn(OrderBook.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
  const mockHandleDataLoad = jest.spyOn(component.dive().instance(), 'handleDataLoad');

  describe('with enzyme', () => {
    it('called componentDidMount', () => {
      expect(didMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }); // this is passed.

    it('called handleScrollEventAttach', () => {
      expect(mockHandleScrollEventAttach).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }); // this is fail. 
  });
});
```

A second test message is "Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times."

I thinks 'handleDataLoad' should have called once because componentDidMount was called. But it's not.

How can I know 'handleDataLoad' call times in react life cycle method?
it's impossible?

**package.json**

```
"react": "15.6.2",
"react-dom": "15.6.2",
"react-redux": "5.0.7",
"redux": "3.7.2",
"babel-jest": "23.2.0",
"enzyme": "^3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.1.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
"react-test-renderer": "15.6.1",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

const mockHandleDataLoad = jest.spyOn(component.dive().instance(),'mockHandleDataLoad');

should be

```
const mockHandleDataLoad = jest.spyOn(component.dive().instance(), 'handleDataLoad');
```

as you are spying on a component instance, you should provide the actual function name.

Also I noticed that you are mocking a store, do your really want to test the connected component? You can only test the inner component by exporting it, check https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md

Comment: Thanks your answer. It’s just my mistake. Actual code have a actual function name so I edited.

Comment: Sorry to hear that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate MyButton.jsx into:

```
MyButton/Component.jsx (holds your component implementation)

MyButton/Container.js (will connect your component to Redux store)
```

In this way you would be able to test your component without any problems. And you would be able to replace Redux in case you need in a future.